# How does one retrieve a previously existing classic style?

Tags: mapbox

Is it possible to retrieve an existing classic style, even though they are no longer supported?

I have a URL that used to point at our style, but now I get json that looks like this:

```
{
message: "Classic styles are no longer supported; see https://blog.mapbox.com/deprecating-studio-classic-styles-d8892ac38cb4 for more information"
}
```

My company was sidelined by the depreciation of classic styles. It required some emergency hotfixes to get things up and running again, but our maps no longer have our signature look. We had a professional design our classic style, and now we want to convert it to MapBox Studio.

Does our previous style still exist? If it does, how can we retrieve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a question for Mapbox support. My guess is that there is no public way to access it, but they may have some way. Or possible archive.org will have a copy of your website that will let you get the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

They wrote on a [blog entry](https://blog.mapbox.com/deprecating-studio-classic-styles-d8892ac38cb4):

> We made the decision to stop active maintenance of the core technology that powers these maps (CartoCSS) back in 2016. However, we continued to support Classic Styles through our Legacy Maps and Legacy Static Images APIs.

Here is the documentation about the Legacy Maps: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/legacy/maps/

In my case, it was faster to change to the new API. The old access token was still working. Here is how to implement it: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/migrate-legacy-static-tiles-api/